# Assgined different classes of bootstrap to an element but it failed to be responsive when the resolution ratio changed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color: aqua;">1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color: antiquewhite;">2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color: burlywood;">3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color: forestgreen;">4</div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I used toggle device toolbar in devtool to switch to smaller devices like Moto G4 but the page seemed to be the same with what I saw under my computer's original resolution. I expected to see two columns in a row when the screen is small, but it turned out to be four rows constantly. Can someone telling me why?

Comment: add `viewport` meta

Comment: A viewport meta tag is important for mobile devices with high density displays, but in desktop developer tools, switching to a simulated mobile view doesn't change to a different display density--rather it only changes the viewport size, so while that is an important suggestion, it likely will not fix this specific issue.

Comment: @Liftoff I don't know why but somehow the solution worked lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a viewport (e.g. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>`) should help:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color: aqua;">1</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color: antiquewhite;">2</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color: burlywood;">3</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="background-color: forestgreen;">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```